# Replicación postgresql amazon rds

Tags: postgresql, aws, postgresql-12, amazon-rds, postgresql-10

Se puede lograr streaming replication con una instancia de postgres fisica a una instancia de postgres en amazon RDS

Comment: Por favor, traduce tu pregunta a español (incluyendo el título)

Comment: No creo, pues desde RDS AWS PostgreSQL no puedes hacer un basebackup hacia tu instancia fisica, pero replicacacion logica si debes poder hacer